# Resize chart.js canvas for printing

Tags: canvas, chart.js

I'm using the `@media print {` to customize my print view. The problem with my charts is that their printing size depends on the size of the browser window. So when my browser is big, the canvas will be too big for the page (I'm using responsive charts)

I have tried to redefine the size of the canvas inside `@media print {` without success.

What are the solutions to get a consistant chart size when I print (without affecting my browser view)?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is the chart does not fit the new print width dimension. Fortunately we can perform a redraw when print is initiated.

The solution is to render your chart to an image using the `canvas.toDataURL()` method when printing is invoked, then switch it back to the canvas chart after printing. [More on toDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL).

To detect when to invoke your functions webkit provide the method `window.matchMedia('print')` (which will be `true` during print or `false` again afterwards) while other browsers use `window.onbeforeprint` and `window.onafterprint`.  [More on print methods](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2012/06/15/detecting-print-requests-with-javascript/).

All that is then left to do is ensure the image is responsive using CSS, i.e. scales to 100% width.

Comment: Anyone know where there is a working example of this?

Comment: This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52754926/chartjs-responsive-resize-for-print-not-working-in-firefox-ie11-edge provide an exemple working in Chrome, but apparently not in Firefox/IE. I confirm it works with Chrome.

Answer (score 32):

If your charts are simple, try using just using css

```
@media print {
    canvas.chart-canvas {
        min-height: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        height: auto!important;
        width: auto!important;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution worked with the react-chartjs-2 wrapper component in my react UI. Much simpler than any of the other solutions that I have looked at to date. I have tested in IE, Chrome, MS Edge. Did not get good preview in Firefox, but I think there  is a problem with Firefox settings. Browser is not not printing any page correctly for me.

Comment: Are we talking about simply adding a class to the canvas? @BrianTatum could you share  your solution?

Comment: This is a god-like answer. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me on version 2.9.4 of Chart.js (tested on Firefox 84 and Chrome 87).

Comment: Sorry, @RakeshVadnal, my memory doesn't go back that far.

Answer (score 0):

I used a custom print style for the canvas with a custom right padding:

```
@media print {
  .chartCanvas {
    padding-right: 1cm;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure how this solves the issue. The canvas still isn't resized because you add padding.

Answer (score 0):

Following the links and Reggie Pinkham's example I was able to make this work in Angular 2.  The example is in typescript but reader's should be able to adapt this to regular JavaScript fairly easily to work in other projects. Note I have only tested this in the latest version of Chrome on a Linux box as that is just fine for my internal company project.

```
// imports left out here
export class ScaleChartComponent implements OnInit {
private chart:Chart;
private chartNode:HTMLCanvasElement;
private chartImage:HTMLImageElement;
private mediaQueryListener:MediaQueryListListener;

// el is a reference to the root node of my angular html component think of it as just a div container.
constructor(private el:ElementRef) { }
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.chart.clear();
  this.chart.destroy();
  this.chart = null;
  this.cleanupPrint();
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.drawChart();
  this.setupPrint();
}
// need to setup the event listeners here and hold a reference to cleanup afterwards.
public setupPrint() {
  if (!window.matchMedia) {
    return;
  }

  var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
  this.mediaQueryListener = this.handlePrintMediaChange.bind(this);
  mediaQueryList.addListener(this.mediaQueryListener);
}
// make sure to cleanup the reference after the fact.
public cleanupPrint() {
  if (!window.matchMedia) {
    return;
  }
  var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');
  mediaQueryList.removeListener(this.mediaQueryListener);
  this.mediaQueryListener = null;
}

// here's where the magic happens. I first grab the image
// then 
public handlePrintMediaChange(mql) {
  if (mql.matches) {
    let dataUrl = this.chartNode.toDataURL('image/png');
    
    if (this.chartNode && this.chartNode.parentNode) {
      this.chartImage = new Image();
      this.chartImage.src = dataUrl;
      this.chartNode.parentNode.appendChild(this.chartImage);
      this.chartService.destroyChart(this.chart);
      this.chartNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.chartNode);
    }

  } else {
  // here is where we switch back to non print mode.
    if (this.chartImage) {
      if (this.chartImage.parentNode) {
        this.chartImage.parentNode.removeChild(this.chartImage);
      }
      this.chartImage = null;
    }
    // go through and recreate the entire chart again.
    this.drawChart();
  }
}

public drawChart() {
  var chartData = {}; // setup your chart data here.
  this.chartNode = this.createChartNode();
  if (this.chartNode) {
    this.chart = ; // execute your chart.js draw commands here.
  }
}
private createChartNode() {
   let componentElement = this.el.nativeElement as Element;
   let element = componentElement.querySelector(".scale-chart-container");
  if (!element) {
    console.error("could not find element with class .scale-chart-container");
    return null;
  }

  let chartNode = document.createElement("canvas") as HTMLCanvasElement;
  element.appendChild(chartNode);
  chartNode = chartNode;
  return chartNode;
}
}
```

Note that I've left out the Chart.js commands and data as that will vary based upon the person.  I have an external service that deals with that which I've left out.

I hope this helps anyone who's scratching their head on how to go off of Reggie's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy fix based on [Reggie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42497034/1109665) which is a little easier to implement than Stephen's answer:

```js
//Fix chartjs printing:
window.onbeforeprint = (ev) => {
    for (var id in Chart.instances) {
        let instance = Chart.instances[id];
        let b64 = instance.toBase64Image();
        let i = new Image();
        //Instead of the below, you could save something on the
        //chart that decides what to change this to. This worked for me
        //however:
        i.style.maxWidth = "100vw";
        i.src = b64;
        let parent = instance.canvas.parentNode;
        instance.tempImage = i;
        instance.oldDisplay = instance.canvas.style.display;
        instance.canvas.style.display = "none";
        parent.appendChild(i);
    }
};

window.onafterprint = (ev) => {
    for (var id in Chart.instances) {
        let instance = Chart.instances[id];
        if (instance.tempImage) {
            let parent = instance.canvas.parentNode;
            parent.removeChild(instance.tempImage);
            instance.canvas.style.display = instance.oldDisplay;
            delete instance.oldDisplay;
            delete instance.tempImage;
        }
    }
};
```